# couldn't receive google glass notification after subscription?

Tags: google-glass, google-mirror-api, callbackurl, google-playground

I have created a timeline card with menu item and subscribed the same.When i try it(clicked the menu item) from mirror api playground ,it shows notification send but my service couldn't receive any notification.Its not showing any sign of hitting my service log also.

Below is my subscription json.

```
{
"kind": "mirror#subscription",
"id": "timeline",
"updated": "2013-12-19T06:27:20.269Z",
"collection": "timeline",
"operation": [
"UPDATE"
],
"callbackUrl": "https://mirrornotifications.appspot.com/forward?url=http://192.xxx.xx.xxx:8080/GlassService/google/service/get_balance",
"verifyToken": "example_user",
"userToken": "email"
}
```

instead of ip address in the callback url i tried with localhost also.i got same result.

Please help me with this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Google subscription does not support local url or proxy. You have to submit public url with SSL support for callback Like **"https://www.yourdomain.com/yourmethod"**.

Another way is, you can use **"Introspected tunnels to localhost"**. then your local url become public and you will get notification after subscription.

Comment: can mirror api playground send notifications or not ? because i tried with google app script https link also  still i could not receive anything.

Comment: actually mirror api can, but in development environment you cannot.

Comment: in development environment in the sense? because this playground shows  notification sent msg.Thats why i got confused.

Comment: when you are going to use html or json, u have to use public url. as far I can find subscription, image.